# Nestjs role guard in form-data "message": "Forbidden resource",

Tags: nestjs, backend, multipartform-data, roles, guard

Hello guys i'm working with nestjs i put the role in the body of request ....but now i'm working with form data because i have files to uploads so  i get always "message": "Forbidden resource", because the body contain no role  `

```
here is the role.guard i'm using the body to know the role 
`Role.guard.ts`

  @Injectable()
   export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
   constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}
``
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
    const requiredRoles = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<Role[]>(ROLES_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (!requiredRoles) {

      return true;
    }
    
    const { body } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
   console.log('==>', context.switchToHttp().getRequest())
   console.log('body should contain data ==>', body)

    console.log('should return true for role==>', requiredRoles.some((role) => body.role?.includes(role)))

    return requiredRoles.some((role) => body.role?.includes(role));
  }
}
```

Candidats.controller.ts
this is the methode that i wont to use like we see i add the role.admin but the role can't be readed in the  form-data

```
 @Post()
  @Roles(Role.Admin)
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard())
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('document'))
  async create(
    @UploadedFile() document: Express.Multer.File,
    @Body() createCandidats: CreateCandidats,
    @GetUser() user: User
  ): Promise<Candidate> {
    console.log("check the documents in express multer====>",document)
    console.log('1 Credentials===>',createCandidats)
    const documentName = document.filename;
    console.log('check the doc name===>',document.filename)
    createCandidats.documents = documentName;

    return await this.candidateService.create(createCandidats, user);
  }
  
}
```

when i test with no roles it work but when i add role it dosn't